# Is it possible in Akka to create a Flow from a Source=>Source function, as with RxJava/Reactor compose?

Tags: akka, rx-java, akka-stream

I still have not found a easy way to do a "filtering" Flow in AkkaStreams. Doing a "mapping" flow is clear to me, with fromFunction, but doing a filtering one is not. In RxJava/Reactor there is a compose operator on Flowable/Observable that takes a function from a Flowable to another Flowable, so then a transformation can be described as a chain of operators, and of course the filter operator on a Source is what I need for a filtering Flow, but it is unclear to me how to define a filtering Flow, though clearly it is easy for me how to filter a Source of course.
Please advise

Comment: You should likely read their documentation: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```scala
// Filter elements which are even (use the modulo operator: `%`)
def filterEvenValues: Flow[Int, Int, NotUsed] =
  Flow[Int].filter(number => number % 2 == 0)
```